# How to send data from activity and get it in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi guys I'm starting in the Android world and as the question suggests, I'm stuck there. I had made some researches and tried some of the answers posted in this community but I can not figure it out.

I have an activity that displays a list of contacts an every item in the list navigate to a detail view once is tapped. My goal is passed de item id to perform a request and display the response.

Here is my attempt:

```
public class PersonDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        // This variables have the right value
        String personName = intent.getStringExtra("personName");
        String personID = intent.getStringExtra("personID");

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        // I'm trying to send this variable to make a request later
        bundle.putString("personID", personID);
        // Set Fragment Arguments
        PersonDetailFragment fragment = new PersonDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        setContentView(R.layout.persons);
    }
}

public class PersonDetailFragment extends Fragment {


    public PersonDetailFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // This throw me a NPE
        String data = null;
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            data = getArguments().getString("personID");
        }
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.person_detail_list, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to setup listener for your items like this:

```
public void onItemClick(ItemView itemView) { 
     personId = itemView.getPersonId(); 
     Fragment detailFragment = PersonDetailFragment.newInstance(personId); 
     getSupportFragmentManager()
               .beginTransaction()
               .replace(your_fragment_container, detailFragment)
               .commit();
}
```

Next step is fragment initializing. It's good practice to use static method for fragment creation. Write this method in appropriate fragment class:

```
public static PersonDetailFragment newInstance(String personId) {
     Bundle args = new Bundle();
     args.putString("personId", personId);
     PersonDetailFragment fragment = new PersonDetailFragment();
     fragment.setArguments(args);
     return fragment;
}
```

Comment: Just to add, the `your_fragment_container` must be added to the `layout.persons` xml, instead of adding the `<fragment>` itself to the layout. More info [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#AddAtRuntime).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to pass any variable after creating the `Fragment` instance, pass the parameter in the constructor like this.

```
PersonDetailFragment fragment = new PersonDetailFragment(personID);
```

Being the constructor of the Fragment like this:

```
public PersonDetailFragment(String personID) {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
```

If you want to communicate constantly with the activity you can implement interfaces. Read this article, It's a good point to start with them, `listeners`.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to add your fragment to your activity?

If your fragment is in the layout xml of the activity, then it is not the same one as the one you are creating and adding arguments to in the Java.

You need to add your fragment to your activity programatically.